# Windows XP control panel control for Windows forms

Tags: winforms, controls, panel

I'd like to have an application with an UI similar to Windows XP control panel. Does anybody knows of a control with the same icon view?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The closest control that could serve this purpose is the ListView control, using the Large Icons view.

It will have a similar look to a control panel.  Unless you are talking about the category based control panel in WindowsXP, then you would have multiple controls and forms to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/FileSystemListView.aspx) shows how to embed the Windows file viewer control in you app, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form/776741#776741) for more info.