# Windows File Explorer control

Tags: c#, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding a File Explorer instance in a WinForms app form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form)

I want a windows explorer style control on my form so i can browse directories for files, and drag them into another section of my form, ideally with filters (eg *.mp3 etc).

I can't find anything that will do exactly as I want. I have found this:

http://hypercoder.com/?page_id=3

I have made the drag and drop work but with no documentation or examples I cannot work out how to double-click into directories in the file viewer and automatically update the tree.

It seems that this type of control must be used all of the time! Does anybody know where I can find something that will work?

TIA

Comment: For which technology (Winforms, WPF)? and what development environment (Visual Studio X, .NET Y)?

Comment: You can probably make your own pretty easily, did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a File Explorer instance in a Windows Forms application form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-windows-forms-application-form)

Answer (score 5):

How about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx), a C# File browser, that works just like Windows Explorer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dave: Great! Why the downvote? LOL! Happy new year to whoever downvoted this! :P

Answer (score 3):

C# .NET 2009

Should have searched stack overflow first. Just found this:

http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

and ran a test it looks perfect!

Comment: It doesn't support UNC paths from what I can tell. A big shortcoming

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't Winodws 7 provide you with one?  WindowsAPI Code Pack also give you one- that works exactly the same way as Windows Explorer, looks the same, accepts files and folders from external resources.  Microsoft made it, no doubt it is really good.
Problem - I THINK it only works on Windows 7...Thumbs down :(

Anways, heres the site: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack
Enjoy!

Comment: WindowsAPICodePack is abandoned by Microsoft, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665).

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebBrowser control, where you can invoke the Navigate() method to a folder path. If you invoke the Navigate() method of a WebBrowser control with a folder path, the WebBrowser will behave same like a windows file explorer.

Comment: Thanks, not a complete control but definitely helps me just wanting to view some files.