#  connect to a remote MS Server and manage specific folder

Tags: c#, connection, remote-server, windows

This is a first for me so I will try to be as specific as I can in this. The intent of the project I have is to connect to a remote server using a Windows application. Once the user signs into the application it will automatically connect to the remote server and open the user's designated folder and display the folders within the Windows application. FTP is not an option at this point.

My question is I have already tried AxMSTSCLib functionality but that is opening a Remote Desktop which is not what I need. Where would I start? Or at least how do I establish a connection with the remote server and display the folder for that user?

Comment: Please don't start your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: I apologize I use that because in the past I have stated in my question and in the tags what the question is referencing, but I still get questions about what programming language are you using or what database are you using, so I do that so I dont get those questions anymore

Comment: Then I suggest you make the language _part_ of the title, like "connect to a remote ... in a C# program"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are trying to implement File Browser sort of functionality in your application. Please see if this link is of any help for you.

[Embedding a File Explorer instance in a Windows Forms application form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form)

Comment: Yes a file explorer, the main exploring willbe done on a remote server location. And they need to login to the remote server too securily

Comment: You can write a sort of service running on remote server listening to requests coming from clients sending the user credentials with their requests. Service would return the clients, folders and filenames and then you can display them in the front end using custom File Browser. Clicking folder name in the file browser should again result in service calls getting the contents of the folder from the service.

Comment: Ok but what api do I use the send a request to a remote server? that is where I am lost

Comment: You can use WCF for building the service to be run on the remote server and then use the corresponding WCF client in your client application.

Comment: Ok so I have to have a service on the remote server then, I can't do it like an windows explorer then huh, that would involve FTP right

Comment: WCF client will communicate with WCF service for getting the files and folder names and after that WCF client would feed the data to the custom File Explorer hosted in the application on the client side. This whole approach does not require any FTP.