# opening Directories like in windows explorer on windows form?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, directory

is it possible to open a directory on windows form?  and show all its contents just like opening it actually like in windows explorer UI?

how, what is the code for this operation? C# code. i cant figure it out

Comment: If I post "Yes, it's possible", do I get it right? This is not an answerable question. I'd suggest you look into the [Windows Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx) and it's available interfaces, which are all useable from C#, and come back with questions that are specific that you need help solving. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of articles on codeproject.com showing how to create a Windows Explorer like UI using standard Winform controls.  These look promising:

[Windows Explorer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tv-lv-basic41.aspx)
[A Windows Explorer in a user control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ExplorerTree.aspx)

There are others though.

I'd start with one of these and modify to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The [ExplorerBrowser C# sample program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356173.aspx) shows how to host an Explorer window inside a Windows Forms form or a WPF window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - see the folder browser control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

You however have to include the shell events when someone double clicks on a file to launch it, such as calling process.start.
There are tons of examples out there and many ways to accomplish this. For ex. a quick google search
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileManager.aspx

[Embedding a File Explorer instance in a Windows Forms application form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form)